# GetValue and SetValue vs INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged when creating BindableProprties?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I usually extend controls by creating bindable properties, in this form:

```
  public static readonly BindableProperty OnTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OnText),
            typeof(string), typeof(TextSwitch), defaultValue: string.Empty, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: HandleOnTextPropertyChanged);

        private static void HandleOnTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            (bindable as TextSwitch)?.Rebuild();
        }

        public string OnText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(OnTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OnTextProperty, value); }
        }
```

for me, since I did some WPF, bindable properties consists of two parts: the static readonly BindableProperty field, and a corresponding property with `GetValue` in getter and `SetValue` in setter. But I stumbled over this: https://github.com/adamped/NavigationMenu/blob/master/NavigationMenu/NavigationMenu/NavigationItem.xaml.cs

which just fire the `PropertyChanged` event :

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Text),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(NavigationItem),
    string.Empty,
    propertyChanging: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
        var ctrl = (NavigationItem)bindable;
        ctrl.Text = (string)newValue;
    },
    defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

private string _text;

public string Text
{
    get { return _text; }
    set
    {
        _text = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

How can this incorporate with the bindable properties to get it working without `GetValue` and `SetValue`?, and in which cases we need to use one approach over another?

EDIT

Apparently I'm not accustomed to the notion of the self binding reusable control.. but isn't calling `GetValue` and `SetValue` essential for binding properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two implementations are the same.

`GetValue(BindableProperty)` and `SetValue` are used to access the values of properties that are implemented by a `BindableProperty`. That is, application developers typically provide an interface for a bound property by defining public property whose get accessor casts the result of `GetValue(BindableProperty)` to the appropriate type and returns it, and whose set accessor uses `SetValue` to set the value on the correct property.

Your achievement

```
private static void HandleOnTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        (bindable as TextSwitch)?.Rebuild();
    }
```

is same with

```
 propertyChanging: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
{
    var ctrl = (NavigationItem)bindable;
    ctrl.Text = (string)newValue;
}
```

Used 
      OnPropertyChanged(); in `setValue`method